# Are there other names of Greek places with the Sta(n)- prefix besides Stalimene and Stanchio in medieval Western Europe?

Tags: middle-ages, greece, hellenistic-greece

I don't know what I can add to the question, except that it is ultimately related to the question of why Istanbul is not called "Istinbul" instead.  The more examples of other Greek places with Stan- instead of the expected Stin- in medieval sources can be identified, the stronger the case will be for this being from a Greek dialect pronunciation other than any documented one in that time period, presumably in some Greek island(s), where it could then be descended from ancient Doric dialects.  The key is to find medieval examples, and ideally before the 1450's.

Comment: Try asking in the Latin community - they have somewhat tricky policy regarding ancient Greek (since it's technically off topic), but there are definitely people with relevant expertise there.

Comment: None of either form seem to have been indexed in [Ptolemy's Geography](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Gazetteer/Periods/Roman/_Texts/Ptolemy/place_index*/S.html)

Comment: I feel like you're halfway into something I'm just catching up on here. It looks like the name Istanbul comes from the Greek phrase "eis tin Polin" (εἰς τὴν πόλιν), meaning "(in)to the city", "Polin" being the "City" part. "The City" is a term commonly used by rural locals the world over [to refer to a nearby culturally dominant city](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/62/79/2c/62792cad5cf333ff98ee0a5a6addf11c.jpg). Why would the "eis tin" (in(to)) part be a common prefix? Or even a prefix at all?

Comment: Not really relevant to your real question, but there are several places starting *Stavr-* or *Staur-* (Σταυρ-) meaning "of the Cross"

Comment: @T.E.D. "Istanbul" ultimately derives from "Constantinople" -> "Constantine" -> "Constans" which is Latin, not Greek. There are lots of other Turkish city names that are versions of the previous Roman/Byzantine names, rendered with Turkish phonetics.

Comment: @Spencer - I was able to dig up one source that calls that an "alternate explanation". It doesn't appear to be the consensus one though, or even the most common. Either way, the question appears to be asking as if the Greek orgin is assumed correct, and asking if anything else uses this bit of Greek. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @T.E.D. It may make moot the whole question as founded on a false premise.  It might be better to confirm via Latin Stack Exchange (which also does Greek) if Medieval Greek has a -sta(n)- element at all.

Comment: Please people.  I don't need and neither do you need apodictic claims like that the name Istanbul derives from Constantinople.  Almost all specialists agree that it does not, and even if we were all wrong, one should at least exist that we do exist, and at least admit that it is controversial.  And since there is a vast literature, I really don't see why I have to "prove" that many Greek place names do or did begin with eis tēn > stēn and others with just eis > s.  This is like saying that the speed of light is not constant because YOU know so.  I assume what is accepted as common knowledge.

Comment: I can of course provide a lengthy bibliography or a list of other examples with s- or with stin-.  But these are all well-known and not controversial at all.  The -a- in Istanbul IS controversial and has been for a long time, but the ONLY reason anyone proposed that the name comes from Constantinople was precisely that he (his name was Rosen) could not explain the -a- of Istanbul from a Greek eta.  But since there is also Stalimene and Stanchio, that will not help.  So what we know is that there are at least these three, but there might be more.  The question has NOTHING to do with Latin.

Comment: @AttilathePun Latin Stack Exchange also fields questions about Greek. Since this is an etymology question, and not a history question,  you're better off asking over there.